# 2>&1 is giving two ouptuts

Tags: linux, bash

I don't have any file called "new" and hence it is redirected to the test.txt(stedrr)

```
cat new 2> test.txt
```

But why I am getting 2 stderr output when I run the below command?

```
cat new 2>&1 test.txt
cat: new: No such file or directory
cat: new: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You are not getting two errors, you are getting one error followed by the contents of test.txt (which just looks like an error). The second command is essentially equivalent to `cat new test.txt 2>&1` (and the `2>&1` part isn't really doing anything -- it's redirecting stderr to the terminal, which is the same place it was going to begin with).

Comment: Can't reproduce. I get only one error message, as expected. The `2>&1` redirection is redundant in your concrete example, but it would matter if you would pipe the output to another command (for instance `cat new test.txt 2>&1|grep new`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I get:

```
$ cat new 2>&1 test.txt
cat: new: No such file or directory
cat: test.txt: No such file or directory
```

Note that it complains about 2 different files.

Explanation.

The syntax for the `cat` command is:

```
cat [OPTION]... [FILE]...
```

In other words, it takes (potentially) multiple files and writes them to standard output.   In the example above, the command is printing `No such file or directory` twice because you have given it 2 different **input** files that do not exist.

Wait?  What?  2 input files?

Yes!!

In your command, `2>&1` means send standard error to the same place as standard output.  But since you did not redirect standard output ... it goes to the console.

If you want both standard error and standard output to go to a file, you need to redirect standard output as well; e.g.

```
$ cat > new 2>&1 test.txt
$ cat new
cat: test.txt: No such file or directory
```

Now `new` will contain the error message that was written to standard error by `cat`!

Conversely, if you wanted the output and errors in `test.txt` it would be:

```
$ cat > test.txt 2>&1 new
$ cat test.txt
cat: new: No such file or directory
```

... or the contents of `new` ... if it existed.

---

So why did you get this?

```
$ cat new 2>&1 test.txt
cat: new: No such file or directory
cat: new: No such file or directory
```

Well my *guess* is that `test.txt` actually exists ... and that it contains

```
cat: new: No such file or directory
```

from the previous attempt:

```
$ cat new 2> test.txt
```

That writes (only!!) the errors to `test.txt`.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I have a file named "text.txt" and that's y I am getting the output